# Loop within category's posts

Tags: categories, loop, pagination, navigation

I'm trying to figure this out since a couple of days, and even though it should be a quick and easy thing, I couldn't find any workaround.

I've 4 categories, and each of it has between 10 and 40 posts.
I activated the prev-next pagination on posts, but when I arrive at the last/first post of category X, the pagination doesn't loop within the category, but it shows the first/last of the prev/next category.

How can I make the pagination looping inside the category the current post is?
So at the last post of category 3, the next button will go at the first post of category 3 again, and so on?

Thanks in advance, this will help me a lot!

Cheers!

EDIT: I'm using the theme called 'Pronto', if this helps!

Comment: Without code, this is going to be impossible to answer. You should be aware, however, that questions dependent upon third party plugins or themes will be off-topic here.

Comment: I'm actually not using a third-party plugin, and I guess the pagination integrated in my theme is something that you can find commonly in other themes as well.
I attached a pastebin link here so you can find the code of the files single.php and pagination.php

http://pastebin.com/f5m2fFm3

thanks!